# Twitter Bootstrap Legacy: Uniform height on spans

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, height

See the following image:

[image]

What I need is to enlarge the B column to match the first column height, or if I had several columns they always maintains the same height, adjusting to the largest column height.

I have been playing for a while without any success with `<div class="clearfix"></div>` and `height: 100%`.

I'm using **Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2**.

**HTML:**

```
 <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <div>
                ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                ABBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
                BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="span6">
            <div>
                B
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url("http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css");

        #main {
            height: 5em;
        }
        .span6 {
            background-color: lightgray;
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .span6 > div {
            background-color: lightblue;
            border: 1px solid green;
        }
```

For some reason the fiddle don't resembles the image with the above code, but if you paste it into a `test.html` it works properly.

**EDIT:**

And how can I align the height of the inner `span div`s?

**EDIT 2:**

With @Coop guidance I finally managed to have this sorted out. I come to the following code:

```
var content_height = [];

jQuery('.row-fluid > div')
    .each(function () {
        content_height.push(jQuery(this).css({minHeight: 0}).height());
    })
    .each(function () {
        jQuery(this).css({

        minHeight: Math.max.apply(Math, content_height)
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yeh this is an age old problem for fluid height spans. I don't like the CSS solutions to this because they're either messy or not backwards compatible. Do you mind using jQuery? If not, I can post a solution with that.

Comment: @Adrift: That don't worked in my original code :( Besides, I need to maintain the width as the default Bootstrap width since I will change later the columns width by changing its span class. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Coop: Sure! Any solution is welcome! :) I prefer a pure CSS one but if yours work fine and there is no CSS solution I will stick with yours! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with a jQuery solution:

First add the class `eHeight` to all divs in a row you want to give the same height.
Then add the jQuery below:

```
$('.eHeight').each(function () {
  var eHeight = $(this).parent().innerHeight();
  $(this).outerHeight(eHeight);
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/VA6D4/

Note that the jQuery needs to be in a `$(window).load` because Google Chrome gives 0 height and width to images before they load.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that jQuery is the best bet here. When I've a working solution I will post it here as a comment.

Comment: Cool. I've played around with lots of CSS solutions and other layouts to achieve this in the past, but came to the conclusion that this simple bit of jQuery is the best solution.

Comment: I managed to fix that by using the code in the EDIT 2. I will mark your answer as accepted since you helped me a lot in the way :) Thanks

Comment: Glad I could help. I sometimes make variations of that code to suit the needs of the design but the concept is there.

Answer (score 3):

See this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2THd/)** You can do it by adding big padding with big negative margin and then wrap your span with `overflow: hidden;`

CSS

```
.sameheight {
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
    background-color:green;
}
.wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Neat! Worked fine! Can you be kind with me and explain the theory behind? How can this zero-result operation with margins, paddings would cause this to work?

Comment: Aah interesting solution. I'd like to know the theory too please.

Comment: Mmmm, I think a began to get it. Just a question remains: if I have a inner div inside the span, with borders and background color, and wants to have the other columns height, how I would do that? If I understand correctly your solution, the bottom border will be clipped with the parent overflow, right?

Comment: Ah yes I get it too now. Yeh the only way you could have a bottom border or custom bottom padding on the content in the div would be to have another div inside. You'd be adding more markup. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/p2THd/2/
This is what I meant by CSS solutions being messy because you often need to add more layers to the structure. jQuery solution avoids this.

Comment: Yeh. I will try your solution now :)